# Turn INSERT INTO query into UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a piece of software that runs an INSERT INTO query in my MySQL database. I'd like this software to update a row in the table it is accessing instead of creating a new row. I have no access to change the query in the software, so I'm wondering if there is some way to make this happen by other means. Is there a setting I can change on my table, or can I create a new view that the software can use that will make this work? Is this even possible?

Comment: You can't change the query at all...?

Comment: Have you tried using a trigger?

Comment: Nope @Explosion, the query is coming from a proprietary piece of software. I can change what table and what fields it accesses, but can't change it to an update unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know very much about triggers so I haven't tried one. How would that work @aarolamabluenk?

Comment: @Aarolama Bluenk: what would you do with trigger actually? You cannot modify the same table in trigger

Comment: I read up a little on triggers. Am I correct in thinking I can make another table which the software can insert into, and then set a trigger which will do the update that I want in the correct table?

Comment: @pjgat09 Can you post your table structure and elaborate on what exactly you want to update when insert happens?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like mysql proxy (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-proxy.html) to modify the query before it hits the database. This can be done without touching the application code.